# Why is the index.html in Angular not applying the stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, angular, hyperlink, styles

I start a Angular App and it works fine but it doesn't appl the stylesheet style.css in the same fooder with index.html (src). Any idea why?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularDemo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <i></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

The background stays white and the letters black until I add the style in the head of the index.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, any asset you add you need to add its reference in angular.json file also. You will find `"styles": [ ]` in angular.json. You can add your stylesheet reference there.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this change the type='text/css' to type='stylesheet'

type equal to stylesheet stands for css files, import for any source.
text/css is commonly used for use head declarations, as you say.

Comment: Hi Erich! Thank you a lot for your answer... unfortunately nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works if I import it in a CSS file instead. E.g.

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```